# Why does one var acts like two separate vars in constructor function?

Tags: javascript, variables, constructor

I understand that foo is a local var and this.foo is a property of 'this'. I'm curious what are the underlying mechanisms responsible for this behaviour. Looks like JS is creating a new this.foo from foo?:

```
function Life(){
  var foo = 0;

  function setFoo(newFoo){ foo = newFoo; }

  function getFoo(){ return foo; }

  function setFooThis(newFoo){ this.foo = newFoo; }

  function getFooThis(){ return this.foo; }

  return { setFoo, setFooThis, getFoo, getFooThis }
}

var organism = new Life();
organism.setFoo(23);
organism.setFooThis(45);
console.log(organism.getFoo()); // 23
console.log(organism.getFooThis()); // 45
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "underlying mechanisms" - they just are two different things. One is part of a scope, the other part of an object.

Comment: "*Looks like JS is creating a new this.foo from foo?*" - No. You are explicitly creating two different things, one with `setFoo(23)` the other with `.setFooThis(45)`

Comment: `var foo` is a closure. read about it here :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures private variable to the `Life()` class

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you are right, I am completely oblivious to the fact that I was explicitly creating them. Thanks

Comment: @Bergi if you combine your comments into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious what are the underlying mechanisms responsible for this behaviour.

They just are two different things. One is part of a scope, the other part of an object.

> Looks like JS is creating a new this.foo from foo?

No. You are explicitly creating two different things, one with `.setFoo(23)` the other with `.setFooThis(45)`.

Answer (score 0):

`organism.getFoo()` returns you the closure value
`organism.getFooThis()` returns the instance value.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Knitesh's answer:

Your `setFooThis` uses `this`, which is references the `Life` function. The `foo` variable in `var foo = 0` is a variable that is scoped to the function, but is not set ON the function. Meaning it cannot be accessed outside the function, but it is still not a part of the function.

You can see this in action by creating a function inside the `Life` function `function printThis(){ return this }` and `console.log` it. You will see something along the lines of

`Object {
    foo: 45,
    setFoo: function,
    setFooThis: function,
    getFoo: function,
    getFooThis: function
}`

If you want to read more about the `this` keyword I recommend checking out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context